# How to get selected month in jQuery full calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

We are using jQuery full calendar for displaying events from database.

I need to display the events below the calendar according to user selected month `onchange`.
I can get data according to event date but I can't get user selected month in jQuery calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {

        left: 'today',
        center: 'prevYear,prev,title, next,nextYear',
        right: ' month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
        prevYear: 'Prev'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [
    <?php foreach ($edumeet_invite_det as $key =>  $edumeet_det): ?> 
    <?php $edumeet_start = $edumeet_det->getFromDate(); ?>
    <?php $edumeet_end = $edumeet_det->getToDate(); ?>
    <?php $title = $edumeet_det->getTitle(); ?> 
        {
            title:'<?php echo $title; ?>',
            start:'<?php echo $edumeet_start ?>',
            end:'<?php echo $edumeet_end ?>',
            allDay: false
        },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        ],

    eventColor: '#378006',    
});
```

This is the calendar function I am using, I need to get user selected month `onchange`.  Does anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe I don't fully understand your quesiton, but it sounds like you just need to know the current month on screen?

FullCalendar has a "getDate" method.

```
function getMonth(){
  var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
  var month_int = date.getMonth();
  //you now have the visible month as an integer from 0-11
}
```

Sorry if this isn't what you were asking.

Comment: Hey guys, i want load `December` month in Fullcalendar with 2 dates enables 14, 15 Dec 2012. how it is possible? plz help me. Thnx

Comment: `date.getMonth(11);` any idea to load only `December` month in fullcamendar

Comment: Not working dear, I am using full calendar version - 4. Getting error "VM10116 jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function" Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The function "getView" which might be useful to you:

- http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/

To get the first day of calendar month:

`$(cal).fullCalendar('getView').start`

To get the last day of calendar month:

`$(cal).fullCalendar('getView').end`

To get the first visible day of calendar: (the last few days of previous month)

`$(cal).fullCalendar('getView').visStart`

To get the last visible day of calendar: (the first few days of next month)

`$(cal).fullCalendar('getView').visEnd`

Comment: $(cal).fullCalendar('getView').start    give me the first visible day.

Comment: This is for v1. .start nor performs as .visStart - http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Comment: Be careful, with v3, it has changed again : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalStart` for the first day of calendar month
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalEnd` for the day after the last day of the month

Answer (score 3):

With last version (2018) need to use this code!

```
jQuery("#your_selector").fullCalendar('getDate').month()
```

Comment: As of 2019, FC no longer relies on JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

**Full Calendar Version - 4**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        ...
        ...
    });

    calendar.render();

    var cdate = calendar.getDate();
    var month_int = cdate.getMonth();
    alert((month_int+1));  // March 2020 month will return 3

});

</script>
```

This solution worked for me. Happy to help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: `month_int` value does not update when I change the month using next or previous button on the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to get the date and below is one where `you can do it when you initialize the calendar` , Using that you can get the date , month and year separately.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());  
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Full calendar v2.6.1 (2016-02-17)**

```
function getMonth() {
  var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
  month = date._d.getMonth()+1
  console.log(month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For v5, you can access the [View Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object) for the [current view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view). This will contain `currentStart`, which will be the start of the interval the view is trying to represent. In month view, this will be the first of the month.

You can then use something like https://momentjs.com/ to parse the date and get the month.

```
const currentMonth = moment(calendar.view.currentStart).month();
```